# is passing class type necessary?

Tags: java, class, generics

```
protected <T> void myMethod(T obj, Class<?> type)
```

I have seen this method signature and I don't understand why the type  of the first argument explicitly passed as an argument. In fact I can get the type from `obj.getClass()`;

```
protected <T> void myMethod(T obj) {
     Class type = obj.getClass();
}
```

Is this just a design choice? Is there anything beneficial for doing the first method?

Comment: What does the method do? What is its javadoc? Your question implies that the type is the type of the first argument. But maybe it's not.

Comment: Assuming type (second argument) is the type of the first argument

Comment: Did you mean `Class<T> type`?

Comment: Add more code, I suppose the `type` parameter has nothing to do with the `obj` parameter

Comment: Beware that `obj` may be an instance of a subclass `S` of `T`, in which case `obj.getClass()` will give you `S`, not `T`.

Comment: "In fact I can get the type from obj.getClass()" No, you cannot in general. `obj` might be `null` or be a subclass of `T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One case I can think of

- Instantiating a primitive array of a given type T, you cannot do this from the type parameter, you need the actual class.

Example

```
private static <T> void foo() {
    T[] bar = new T[1];  // <== not allowed
}
```

With a class parameter

```
private static <T> void bar(Class<T> clazz) {
    T[] bar = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second implementation is actually the better one. In the first one, you might pass inconsistent parameters. E.g. you could pass an object of class A and pass integer as the second parameter. Therefore your code would be more vulnerable concerning typing errors.